# Flyway migrations not persistent in H2 embedded database

Tags: spring-data-jpa, h2, flyway

I'm actually writing a small web application with spring boot and wanted to use a (embedded) H2 database together with Spring Data JPA and Flyway for database migration.

This is my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/database;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;
spring.datasource.username=admin
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

In the main() method of my @SpringBootApplication class I do the following:

```
ResourceBundle applicationProperties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application");
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
flyway.setDataSource(applicationProperties.getString("spring.datasource.url"), applicationProperties.getString("spring.datasource.username"), applicationProperties.getString("spring.datasource.password"));
flyway.migrate();
```

I added a script, which creates a table USER in the database, Flyway says it is correctly migrated, but if I connect to the database, in schema PUBLIC theres only the schema_versions table of Flyway listed.

If I am adding another script, which inserts base data into the USER table, the migration failes, because the table is not present after a restart of my spring boot application.

Can anyone tell me if there is missing in my configuration? Or if there is any wrong assumption in my setup...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have not enough data about your configuration

1. Hint: 
   See migration file must be part of dicrectory /db/migration
2. Hint
   use a pattern like V1.0.1__name.sql 2 under scores
3. Hint 
   depending on Flyway version you should start with a sql file version greater than 1.0 example 1.0.1.
4. Hint per default spring boot jpa drops your database content if you using a in memory database. See http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html section 28.3.3.

Comment: The fourth hint solved my issue! After adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to my `application.properties`, Spring data and flyway are doing the designated job properly. Thank you very much for your reply!

Comment: works flawlessly! able to insert data using flyway now to h2 database.