# Flyway integration with spring boot doesn't execute migration scripts on embedded H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, h2, flyway

I am trying to make migration demo on embedded H2 data base in Spring Boot application using Flyway.

**application.properties**

```
logging.level.org.org.springframework=DEBUG
server.port=8181
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

migration-script(V2__create_shipwreck.sql) under db/migration

```
CREATE TABLE SHIPWRECK(ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NAME VARCHAR(255),
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(2000),
    CONDITION VARCHAR(255),
    DEPTH INT,
    LATITUDE DOUBLE,
    LANGITUDE DOUBLE,
    YEARS_DISCOERED INT);
```

**console log**

> INFO 7284 --- [main] o.f.c.internal.database.DatabaseFactory:
>   Database: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb (H2 1.4)
>
> INFO 7284 --- [main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbValidate:
>   Successfully validated 1 migration (execution time 00:00.031s)
>
> INFO 7284 --- [main] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory: Creating Schema
>   History table: "PUBLIC"."flyway_schema_history"
>
> INFO 7284 --- [main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate: Current
>   version of schema "PUBLIC": << Empty Schema >>
>
> INFO 7284 --- [main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate: Migrating
>   schema "PUBLIC" to version 2 - create shipwreck
>
> INFO 7284 --- [main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate :
>   Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time
>   00:00.098s)
>
> INFO 7284 --- [main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean :
>   Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit
>   'default'
>
> INFO 7284 --- [main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  :
>   HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default...]
>
> main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate
>   Core {5.2.14.Final}
>
> main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206:
>   hibernate.properties not found
>
> main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001:
>   Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
>
> main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using
>   dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
>
> main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA
>   EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>das-boot</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**H2 database tables UI**

[image: database tables]

After starting the Spring Boot application, the table has not been created, so what's the problem here?

Comment: Please include `pom.xml`

Comment: @LuayAbdulraheem  I have been added pom.xml

Comment: Your logs are saying the opposite: "Migrating schema "PUBLIC" to version 2 - create shipwreck" & "Successfully applied 1 migration to schema "PUBLIC" (execution time 00:00.098s)". How did you check if the table in the migration script has not been created?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, it was solved after making the change to application.properties as 
datasource.url to **file** instead of **mem**

able to create table with details
Correct:
`spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/dasboot`

application.properties

```
logging.level.org.org.springframework=DEBUG
server.port=8080

spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/dasboot
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver

spring.flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>das-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <name>das-boot</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[shipwreck table was created and persisted in h2 db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByGqM.png)

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description (Flyway executes properly, but no schema changes are observed afterwards) this sounds like Spring Boot does not persist the H2 changes. You might try to add `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` to your `application.properties` so that JPA configuration does not override your schema changes following the Flyway migration, as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012241/flyway-migrations-not-persistent-in-h2-embedded-database?rq=1).

Comment: Thank you for your reply , I have been made the above , but it is still the same .